# B2B Guest invites failing with 503 Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I've invited some guests into my domain. They are added successfully, but when they confirm the invitation, the user gets a 503 gateway error from invitations.microsoft.com

Comment: intermittent errors. Refresh the page with invitations..., should be OK.

Comment: Thank you @astaykov was this a temporary problem yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar intermittent failures couple of times already. Simple refresh - either immediately or after couple of seconds/minutes should resolve the issue.

If the issue persist for longer then couple minutes you should open a support ticket.